# Kaffara for not being able to pay borrowed money

Tags: tawba

I owe several people some money. I calculated the total to be around $500. How I owe them is pretty shameful to say, it is close to stealing. Although they would probably never know I owe them, but I feel bad and I want to pay them back. But sadly I cannot afford it now. So is there any Kaffara (like fasting) for this?

Also if I give the Kaffara now and later pay the money back when I am able to, will this Kaffara be regarded as Nafl?

Comment: You have to try your best to return the money even if you have to borrow as this is Haqooq ul Ebaad and Allah will not forgive unless those people forgive you, and do Toba from this sin. Give charity and expect Allah Rehman o Rahim will forgive you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Islam rights are in two main category:

1- The rights of God, like prayer, fasting,... (that have no relation to other people)

2- The rights of people. like stealing, cheating, riba,...

The kaffare of the 2nd right is returning the lost right. It is better to be backed in its current value. And there is no need for you to explain him what the money that you are returning to him is for. For example, if you can give back the money in form of a gift or you can transfer the money to his bank account without him knowing you.

Anyway the right should be returned to the rightful owner.

If you start moving and striving in the way of Allah, Allah Himself will help you to sooner payback the violated rights.

**References:**

[Repentance](http://www.al-islam.org/the-characteristics-of-a-muslim-al-balagh/repentance)

[Repentance and Self-cleansing](http://www.al-islam.org/self-building-ayatullah-ibrahim-amini/repentance-and-self-cleansing)

[A Divine Perspective on Rights](http://www.al-islam.org/divine-perspective-on-rights-a-commentary-of-imam-sajjads-treatise-of-rights)